# Replace strings in variable using lookup vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a dataframe df with a character variable and the fromvec and tovec.

```
df <- tibble(var = c("A", "B", "C", "a", "E", "D", "b"))

fromvec <- c("A", "B", "C")

tovec <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
```

Use strings in fromvec, check them in df and then replace them with the corresponding strings in tovec so that "A" in df gets replaced with "X", "B" with "Y" and so on to get the desired_df.

```
desired_df <- tibble(var = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "E", "D", "Y"))
```

I tried following, but not getting the desired result!

```
from_vec <- paste(fromvec, collapse="|") 
to_vec <- paste(tovec, collapse="|") 

undesired_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(var = str_replace(str_to_upper(var), from_vec, to_vec))
```

i.e. this

```
tibble(var = c("X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "E", "D", "X|Y|Z"))
```

How can I get the desired_df?

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: I am getting this tibble(var = c("X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "X|Y|Z", "E", "D", "X|Y|Z"))

Comment: replacing variables in `fromvec` with those in `tovec` would yield the result `X, Y, Z, a E D b` unless you specify you'd like result to be case insensitive. If this is the case (as most contributors assumed), please specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `chartr` :

```
df$var <- chartr(paste(fromvec,collapse=""),
                 paste(tovec,collapse=""),
                 toupper(df$var))
# # A tibble: 7 x 1
#   var  
#   <chr>
# 1 X    
# 2 Y    
# 3 Z    
# 4 X    
# 5 E    
# 6 D    
# 7 Y
```

---

Or we can use `recode`

```
library(dplyr)
df$var <- recode(toupper(df$var), !!!setNames(tovec,fromvec))
```

---

If you really want to use `str_replace` you could do:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df$var <- reduce2(fromvec, tovec, str_replace, .init=toupper(df$var))
```

Comment: Wow...That's elegant! Can this be done using str_replace as well?

Comment: in the `recode` solution, can you explain why three `!!!` and not two? Or one? The bangbangs are a real mystery.

Comment: Yes it takes a while to get used to it! `!!!` and `!!` are completely different animals. `!!!` is used in front of a list to distribute its elements to the `...` argument. In base R `do.call` is necessary in these situations.  It can be used only in functions that are programmed to understand it, so mostly `tidyverse` functions. Check my answer and comments there and come back here if you need more explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684613/how-can-i-create-a-new-dataframe-comparing-values-and-getting-only-most-recent-d .

Comment: Very powerful the `reduce2()` anwser :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this with stringr is with `str_replace_all`:

```
mutate(df,str_replace_all(str_to_upper(var),setNames(tovec, fromvec)))
```

(thanks, @Moody_Mudskipper!)

Comment: Nice, for OP to use it however: `mutate(df,str_replace_all(str_to_upper(var),setNames(tovec, fromvec)))`

Comment: Ah! That's a very helpful trick indeed! Thanks, @Moody_Mudskipper!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R`

```
with(df, ifelse(toupper(var) %in% fromvec, 
           setNames(tovec, fromvec)[toupper(var)], var))
#[1] "X" "Y" "Z" "X" "E" "D" "Y"
```

which can be also written in two lines by creating a logical condition

```
i1 <- toupper(df$var) %in% fromvec
df$var[i1] <- setNames(tovec, fromvec)[toupper(df$var)[i1]]
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[toupper(var) %in% fromvec, var := setNames(tovec, fromvec)[toupper(var)]]
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks, akrun! Can this be achieved using stringr as well?

Comment: @Geet  I guess there is an answer below using `stringr`.  May be have to add a condition with `ifelse`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear the result should be case insensitive.

In my opinion, replacement (update) operations that involve an indeterminate number of changes are best accomplished using JOINs. In this case, it also cements a good practice of tracking your changes in a separate dataframe.

Unfortunately, the tidyverse has no "update dataframe" function....a *glaring* omission. That means tidyverse-ers must use a work-around, `coalesce`.

```
#JOIN Operation
tibble(fromvec, tovec) %>%                       #< dataframe of changes
  right_join(df, by = c("fromvec" = "var")) %>%  #< join operation
  transmute(var = coalesce(tovec, fromvec))      #< coalesce work-around

# A tibble: 7 x 1
  var  
  <chr>
1 X    
2 Y    
3 Z    
4 a    
5 E    
6 D    
7 b
```

If a case insensitive operation is preferred, consider inserting `str_to_upper` in the pipeline:

```
tibble(fromvec, tovec) %>% 
  right_join(df %>% mutate(var = (str_to_upper(var))),  #<modify case 
             by = c("fromvec" = "var")) %>% 
  transmute(var = coalesce(tovec, fromvec))

# A tibble: 7 x 1
  var  
  <chr>
1 X    
2 Y    
3 Z    
4 X    
5 E    
6 D    
7 Y
```